# Save pdf to HDFS using pyspark

Tags: pdf, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to save a pdf file to HDFS using pyspark and I am having issues finding examples to do so. The data out there mostly shows how to save csv files which I can do just fine. Below is the code I tried

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import requests
import urllib
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import *
from pyspark import SparkFiles

#spark connection
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext #I don't think this part works

today = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
pdfLocation = "hdfs://nameservice1/Report/Report." + str(today) + ".pdf"
sc.addFile(pdfLocation)

link1 = "https://file.pdf"
response1 = requests.get(link1)

with open(SparkFiles.get(pdfLocation)) as f: 
    f.write(response.content)
```

I get an error that the file does not exist, but I thought I created it in the sc.addFile line

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?